# A simple sql code request

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-like

I need a simple sql code which does the following:

In table1, I got the column codename and it's `varchar(128)`. In table2, I got the column codename as well but there is a little difference between the contents in these columns.

In `table1`, the codename is : `item_pinnacle_w_clothes_10_aa_c_crusader`

In `table2`, the codename is : `ITEM_10_CRUSADER_CH_W_CLOTHES`

Is there any possible way to write a query that is like :

```
from table1 tbl
join table2 tbl2
on tbl.codename like a part from tbl2.codename
```

Comment: duplicate column name in same table ? It seems typo mistake in your question. Please review once.

Answer (score 0):

> Column name doesn't matter, just make sure column has **same data type.**

From SQLFiddle, you can see last query failed, since I was trying to make join between two different data type. So, as far as data type is same. You can join.

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1114/5)**

So answer is **YES**.

Comment: Yep, they have the same data type. They both are varchar(128). I just need to do as stated in my question ^^

Comment: You can write normal join  query. What you mentioned should work as far as you have used same data type. If contents are same in both table then, it will return rows otherwise. It won't. :) I hope, you got my point.

Comment: Well, I guess you didn't really understand what I meant. In table1 I got the column codename, and the value inside it is 'item_pinnacle_w_clothes_10_aa_c_crusader', In table2 I got the column codename, and the value inside it is : 'ITEM_10_CRUSADER_CH_W_CLOTHES'
What I wanna do is updating a third table, the third table is connected to table1, I wanna update a certain column in the third table and set it to the ID in table2.

Comment: I've used join, like statements and they didn't return any row since there is a little difference between 'em both.

Comment: How would they ? Your data are different. You can ask Bird information by passing Animal details. Am I right ?

Comment: Let me re-explain it, I'll be clearer this time and share screenshots.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7v44xi    >> Refobjcommon table, the 6 columns i use in where  blabla like clause
http://prntscr.com/7v45id   >>RefSetItemGroup table

There is a third table, the ID inside it is equal to a column in refobjcommon so joining them together wont be hard, the hard part is joining refobjcommon codename128 with refsetitemgroup codename128

Answer (score 0):

Get the part of text you want to match using substring function and Use Like operator in Join Condition.

Comment: This could work but I need to update 28k rows, and each row has a different codename column, so substring wouldn't really work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the code seems difficult and error prone to do simple `LIKE` matching.

To play safe, create a mapping table for all code between table1 and table2, review the matching and debug carefully. Then join the table1 and table2 with the mapping table

Assume the code is 1 to 1 mapping. Suggested table schema of mapping table:

```
Table1CodeName varchar(128) primary key,
Table2CodeName varchar(128) not null
```

Joining condition

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    t2.*
FROM 
Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Mapping map ON t1.CodeName = map.Table1CodeName 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.CodeName = map.Table2CodeName
```

Comment: Nice idea! This will definitely do what I wanted. Thank you =)

Comment: Well, I couldn't match table1codename with table2codename

Comment: So, after writing my query, the result was table1codename not similar to  table2codename. They were literally different.